# Chrome's text sizing from accessibility is not applying everywhere on the page

Tags: html, css

I am seeing this page https://www.dkc.ae/contact-us on chrome - Android with these settings in chrome accessibility.

[image]

What I realize is that phone numbers are different sizes even though they are applied the same font size from CSS, and `-webkit-text-size-adjust` is 100% for the `html` tag already. but the text sizing is not applied to whatsapp numbers as seen in the bellow screenshot, they look bigger than than the first phone number :

[image]

You can see that same font size is applied to both of them.